# drupal ajax call from click of a link in form

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, hyperlink

How do I submit a form using AJAX when clicking a link in Drupal?

```
function search_form($form,$form_state) {
  $form['support_email'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'link',
    '#text' => '',
    '#ajax' =>array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_change',
      'wrapper' => 'email-hidden',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'click' => 'true',
    ),
  );
}
```

This is the form link I have inside a form. On clicking the link, I want the AJAX callback function `ajax_change` to be called, which does not seem to be happening.

Comment: fill in some text in key '#text' and see if it works.

Comment: No Vishal doesnot work.... I am researching in using ctools to ajax submit the form now.

Answer (score 2):

The forms api reference for the [#ajax](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) functionality says that it is "Used by: button, checkbox, checkboxes, image button, password, radio, radios, select, submit, tableselect, textarea, text_format, textfield". Link is not in the list and thus won't work. The #ajax functionality makes Drupal perform an AJAX call when the specified form element changes. Since a link doesn't change, it is logical that it doesnt work.

The [Asaf (ajax submit for any form)](https://drupal.org/project/asaf) module may be able to help you to achieve what you want to do.

Also, it appears you are trying to use this AJAX to hide an element. The Forms API has a [states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) functionality that makes it easy to conditionally show/hide elements. Read [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHgQFjAJ&url=http://randyfay.com/states&ei=W5H9Uby2GdGt4AP2wIG4BA&usg=AFQjCNEpn-HUwI5CoCOwIEvTrPw60gWfAA&sig2=ttk_DOWwP21uGVTw5qU7nA&bvm=bv.50165853,d.dmg) for more info about states.

The #ajax callback is used to make a form that dynamically changes itself.

Comment: I am hiding the submit button for now on the form and once I click the link submit the form. Submit button has an #ajax so i call it through that..

Comment: You need to add some javascript/jQuery to do that. You can include JavaScript using the ["#attached"] attribute. Why do you want the user to click a link instead of a button. A form can have many submit buttons and you can theme them to look like links.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal it's not possible (without using third party modules) to use link tag as an AJAX triggering element. The alternative solution may be to create a hidden button element with AJAX functionality, and make link trigger click event on that hidden button.

Here is form function:

```
function mymodule__form($form, $form_state) {
  // JS file contains the code for triggering click event on e hidden button.
  $form['#attached']['js'][] =
    drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.behaviors.js';

  // Our link element.
  $form['link_mymodule'] = array(
    '#type' => 'link',
    '#name' => 'link_mymodule',
    '#title' => t('Perform mymodule logic'),
    '#href' => current_path(),
    '#options' => array(
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('mymodule_ajax'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  // Hidden AJAX enabled submit button.
  $form['mymodule_ajax_submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => 'AJAX submit',
    '#name' => 'mymodule_ajax_submit',

    // You may need this to disable validation.
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),

    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_mymodule__form__pager_callback',
      'event' => 'click',
    ),
    '#attributes' => array(
      // Class "element-hidden" will hide the button.
      'class' => array('element-hidden', 'mymodule_ajax_submit'),
    ),
  );

  // Some element for tests.
  $form['random_thing'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => rand(1, 10000),

    // Wrapper is needed since AJAX will use it as a container for incoming data.
    '#prefix' => '<div class="ajax_wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

You will also need callback function for replacing old data with new one since you are using AJAX:

```
function _mymodule__form__pager_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
      ajax_command_replace('.ajax_wrapper', trim(render($form['random_thing']))),
    ),
  );
}
```

Also you will have to attach click event to your link, which will trigger click event on a hidden button. That's what stored in `/js/mymodule.behaviors.js` file.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Since behaviors will be executed every times AJAX is called, it's better to use $.once() method even if you
      // are going to use "context" argument. That is needed to be sure that event is attached only once.
      $('.mymodule_ajax', context).once('mymodule_ajax', function () {

        // Bind click event to out link.
        $(this).click(function (e) {
          // Prevent browser to follow the link.
          e.preventDefault();

          // Perform click triggering.
          $('input.mymodule_ajax_submit').click();
        });

      });

    }
  }
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

Comment: Thanks for your copyright warning, @ArtjomB. I have written a new extended answer with free code and explanations, so no problem any more. Thanks for your comment.